# IE9 Switches to compatibility mode on our host server but not on localhost

Tags: internet-explorer, quirks-mode

we have a problem where we've added the meta tag

```
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```

on localhost IE9 respects this and renders in standards mode. However when we deploy to our staging server it doesn't. It switches to compatibility mode.

Both machines have IIS 7.5, not sure if there's anything else I can add to help find the problem?

Comment: just making sure. you do have a proper doctype at the very top with no XML prologue or UTF-8 BOM right?

Comment: sure do <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: are you reffering to the Browser mode or Document mode? Try an older DOCTYPE, put the meta after stylesheets, check for UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: Browser mode switches to IE9 Compatibility Document Mode switches to IE7 standards.